# How to return the number of empty fields in an object?

Tags: django

I am trying to create a progress bar feature where it tells you your progress by what data you have inserted into your profile. The idea is that it takes all the fields that are empty and subtracts it from the total number of fields.

How do I get all empty fields and return it as a number?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bool()` to check for "empty" fields.

```
fields = instance._meta.fields
empty = sum(bool(getattr(instance, field.attname)) for field in fields)
```

You might want to restrict this to only checking certain field types, for example CharFields and TextFields.

```
fields = [f for f in instance._meta.fields if isinstance(f, (TextField, CharField))]
```

You can add this as a method or property on your model class. In this case, `progress` will return a number between 0 and 1.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def progress(self):
        text_fields = [f for f in self._meta.fields if isinstance(f, (TextField, CharField))]
        values = (getattr(self, field.attname) for field in text_fields)
        return sum(bool(value) for value in values) / len(text_fields)
```